# MATLAB - Save last Folder in Path as a character String? (Syntax)

Tags: matlab, syntax, path, directory, character

```
Ball='C:\----\--\Documents\----\ -----\ Ball - BEST';
```

Given the path to a directory, how do you save the immediate directory as a character string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html):

```
[p, fname, ext] = fileparts(p);
top = strcat(fname, ext);
```

This peels off the last folder from path `p` in `top`. The `ext` must be preserved in case the folder name has a dot it it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UNIX command "pwd"

```matlab
% On C:\----\--\Documents\----\ -----\ Ball - BEST directory
Ball = pwd;
% Ball = 'C:\----\--\Documents\----\ -----\ Ball - BEST'
```